# Extended template block not taking css from static

Tags: python, css, django, python-2.7, django-templates

Below shown extended html of an app for a class based view is not taking css from static file as mentioned in html.
Please help in how to implement css for this extended block.

> HTML File:

```
{% extends "base_template.html" %}

{%block css%}
 {% load static %}
 <link href="{%static 'css/custom.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{%endblock%} 
{% block content %}


 <h2>Dynamic content</h2>

 <p>You have visited this page {{ num_visits }}{% if num_visits == 1 %} time{% else %} times{% endif %}.</p>

 <div class="btnlayout" style="float: left;padding: 10px;">
    <li><form action="/ekmmsc/treedump/printx" method="get">
       <input type="text" value="8" name="mytextbox" size="1"/>
       <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Click" name="mybtn">
    </form></li>

    <li><form action="/ekmmsc/treedump/Tree70" method="get">
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Tree70" name="mybtn1">
    </form></li>

    <li><form action="/ekmmsc/treedump/UserID" method="get">
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="UserID" name="mybtn2">
    </form></li>

    <li> <form action="/ekmmsc/treedump/TG_Dump" method="get">
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="TG_Dump" name="mybtn3">
    </form></li>

 </div>


{% endblock %}
```

> Custom.css

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: black;
    }

.btnlayout li form{
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 80px;
}

.btnlayout li {
    float: left;
    border-right:1px solid #bbb;
    border-left:1px solid #bbb;
}
```

> base_template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>EKMMSC</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link href="{%static 'css/style1.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    {% block css %}{% endblock %}


</head>
```

I need the form elements to be displayed inline where as they are getting displayed as list.

**Custom.css is present inside /static/css/* **
And static files are getting loaded as i have cross checked by putting image but css file isnt loading.

Comment: Have you checked if your browser throws an error, e.g. the CSS can't be found?

Comment: Do you have a `head` block in your base template? Where is `custom.css` stored in your project tree?

Comment: @solarissmoke have updated can you please update....